# Is there a journaling solution for the Mail Enable server?

Tags: email-server, email

we use Mail Enable Professional Edition version 4.3 on Windows Server 2008 R2. We are putting together an e-mail continuity/contingency plan, but all the services we have looked at require e-mail journaling on the part of the server.  From what I can gather from their website, neither our version or the newest version of Mail Enable have journaling as a feature.  I've been looking into journaling products such as Barracuda, but they seem to only work with Exchange/Domino.

Does anyone know of a way to journal with Mail Enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not true journaling with their software as far as I can see.

This KB article from them appears to be the closest you'll get to journaling with them:

http://www.mailenable.com/kb/Content/Article.asp?ID=me020395

[image]

Comment: This may work.  For an e-mail continuity solution the only messages that we need journaled are internal messages (i.e. from me@example.com to you@example.com), all other messages are automatically recorded by the continuity service.  With this module, I think I could create a filter that forwards all internal messages to the external service, but I'm not sure if they will recognize it correctly.  I guess I will have to check with them and learn about the details of journaling.